# Dell Latitude 5430 no external video output with Rocky 9

Tags: rhel, video

I'm testing a Dell Latitude 5430 laptop to see if it will work with Rocky 9, a derivative of RHEL 9. So far everything is working except the external video connections. The laptop has three options for video out, HDMI(built-in), DisplayPort over USB-C, and Thunderbolt 4. All of them do work under Windows so I have ruled out a hardware failure issue. I also tried Ubuntu, which worked, but Rocky, or another RHEL based distro, is required by management for "Reasons".

I first tried the DisplayPort over USB-C option via a Dell WD19S USB-C dock. All functions of the dock worked except the DisplayPort(s). After installing the displaylink-rpm software and dependencies, and signing the kernel module for UEFI secure boot, nothing changed. The driver is active and the module loaded but the external monitor still is not detected by xrandr or GNOME.

I then tried the HDMI port. No output and the external monitor is still not detected. Lastly I tried a known working TB3 dock with a single DisplayPort output. The dock is detected as a TB device but the external monitor is still not working.

I'm aware that DisplayLink is very much not officially supported on RPM distros. That said the HDMI should still work, or at least I would think it should. I'm thinking that this may be an Intel issue as this laptop uses a 12th gen i5 with Intel's UHD "GPU".

If anyone has any info on this laptop working with RHEL based distros please let me know. I'd like to get this working if possible.